# Getting distinct values in a column in orm

Tags: orm, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I can pull data via

```
   <cfquery name="keyTypeGroup">
      SELECT DISTINCT keyTypeGroup
      FROM data.keyType
   </cfquery>
```

I can pull all the data via orm

```
...
return EntityLoad("data_KeyType");
...
```

I have tied

```
   <cfdump var="#ORMExecuteQuery('SELECT DISTINCT KeyGroupType FROM data.KeyType', true)#">
```

But I get

```
Error while executing the Hibernate query. 

org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: data.KeyType is not mapped [SELECT DISTINCT KeyGroupType FROM data.KeyType]
```

How should I approach fixing this?

Comment: The error isn't complaining about your use of `distinct` (which should work) but that you are calling it `FROM data.KeyType`.  That doesn't seem to be the correct name for the ORM entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<cfdump var="#ORMExecuteQuery('SELECT DISTINCT KeyGroupType FROM data.keyType', true)#">
```

I have seen issues with case in situations like this.